# Pandas writing in csv file as columns not rows-Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

This is my code:

```
import os

file=[]

directory ='/Users/xxxx/Documents/sample/'
for i in os.listdir(directory):
   file.append(i)


Com = list(file)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=Com)
df.to_csv('com.csv', index=False, header=True)

print('done')
```

at the moment I am getting all the values for `i` in one column as a row header. Does anyone know how to make each `i` value in one row as a column header?

Comment: IIUC you can transpose the df: `df=pd.DataFrame(data=Com).T` prior to writing out to csv

Comment: @EdChum oh wow, yeah that works perfectly. Thanks alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to transpose the df first using [`.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) prior to writing out to csv:

```
In [44]:
l = list('abc')
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df

Out[44]:
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

compare with:

```
In [45]:
df = pd.DataFrame(l).T
df

Out[45]:
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to prefer `df.T` over [`df.transpose()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose)?  I imagine they are exactly the same under the hood. To me `.transpose()` seems more self-documenting, but perhaps that's not idiomatic pandas.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it's a [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) convention, if you're coming from numpy then it should be familiar to the reader, plus if you hate typing